# Why am I getting "Undefined attribute name" warnings in Eclipse Indigo with php sdk?

Tags: php, warnings, eclipse-indigo

Has anyone experienced this? or does anyone know 
why I am getting "undefined attribute name" warnings in Eclipse Indigo with PHP SDK?

this only occurs when I place  tags inside html tags, i.e.

```
<span <?php echo ($test_var) ? 'class="active"' : '' ?> >text here</span>
```

but this is ok :

```
<ul>
<?php if( $test ) : ?>
<li>text</li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

I just installed Eclipse Indigo and added the PDT SDK, i never had this 
kind of warning with galileo ... helios

Comment: I remember this from an older version of Eclipse. Seems to be one of those things they keep breaking and then fixing in WST (the plugin behind HTML / JS / CSS support). Search the bug tracker and / or file a new bug. In any case, it's just an IDE warning, ignore it

Comment: it can be pretty annoying, specially when i want to just verify that my markup is correct ( no missing closing tags , etc ). but thanks, i'll keep an eye on the plugin's updates.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can disable that particular warning. Have a dig through the preferences dialogs

Comment: I did, although I really wish I didn't have to. It just feels like the '@' for php.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error by placing a form tag inside a table cell. This appears to be an Eclipse issue.. as the Mozilla FF Web Developer Toolbar is telling me my page is in "Standards Compliance Mode".

My page is local right now, but when I get it live I'll test it against the W3C Markup Validation Service and update my answer with the results.